# Отрицание в INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Нужно чтобы из **tasks** не показывались те материалы, id которых записан в **tasks_done**.

```
SELECT ...
FROM `tasks` 
 INNER JOIN `users` ON tasks.tfrom = users.uid 
 INNER JOIN `tasks_done` ON tasks.tid != tasks_done.tdtid 
ORDER BY tasks.tamount DESC LIMIT 10
```

С самим запросом всё нормально. Но вот `ON tasks.tid != tasks_done.tdtid` **не хочет срабатывать**.

- Структура таблицы tasks -

  [image: img1]
- Структура таблицы users -

  [image: img2]
- Структура таблицы tasks_done -

  [image: img3]

Comment: Может так?

     select from `tasks` inner `users` on  tasks.tfrom = users.uid
       where tasks.tid not in (select tdtid from tasks_done)
       ORDER BY tasks.tamount DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: @alexlz, не хотелось бы так. not in очень плохо для оптимизации, да и ещё в подарок вложенный запрос.

Comment: @ModaL тогда объясните, что значит "не хочет срабатывать"? Включает записи, невзирая на присутствие tidtd в tasks_done? Да ещё и размножает? Если да, то поступает правильно, как Вы написали. Вы уж определитесь, что Вы хотите. Сформулируйте хотя бы словами поконкретней, типа: tid из tasks не совпадает ни с одним tdtid из tasks_done

Comment: @alexlz, вот. Размножает. Как это исправить?

Comment: @ModaL так "not in" ("не содержатся"). И, кстати, что за проблемы с оптимизацией? Хроника пикирующего сервера?

Comment: @alexlz, нет, пока только разрабатываю. Цель - всё быстро и чтобы не нагружало. А в мой запрос возможно добавить not in?

Comment: @ModaL я пропустил в своём примере Ваши три точки (список полей в результате) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не смотрели в сторону [LEFT (RIGHT) OUTER JOIN](http://eddnet.org/?p=1580)?

**UPD*#1***: Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tasks 
  INNER JOIN users ON tasks.tfrom = users.uid 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_done ON tasks.tid = tasks_done.tdtid 
  WHERE tasks_done.tdtid is null
```

Comment: А потом выбрать из результата строки с tidtd равным NULL? Хитрый ход...

Comment: @alexlz, именно!

Comment: @Rams666, составил запрос, выдаёт пустоту...
     SELECT * FROM tasks
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users
   ON tasks.tfrom = users.uid
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN tasks_done ON tasks.tid != tasks_done.tdtid
   WHERE tasks_done.tdtid is null

Comment: Попробуйте ON tasks.tid = tasks_done.tdtid ?

Comment: @Rams666, не помогло. А если убрать WHERE tasks_done.tdtid is null, то он показывает только те материалы, id которых записан в tasks_done

Comment: Даже смешнее 

     select * from (select tasks.*, tasks_done.tdtid from
       tasks left join tasks_done on tasks.tid = tasks_done.tdtid) a
     where tdtid is null

(если с синтаксисом не наврал). Вобщем -- мрак.

Comment: @alexlz, вложенный запрос не хочется.

Comment: Похоже я тут перемудрил. Но всё равно идея с outer join мне кажется слишком уродливой. И уж точно не самой эффективной.

Comment: @alexlz, а как иначе то? Вложенные запросы ведь тоже не хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Кому интересно, поколдовал с LEFT OUTER JOIN и всё прекрасно стало работать:

```
  SELECT ... 
   FROM `tasks`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON tasks.tfrom = users.uid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `tasks_done` ON tasks.tid = tasks_done.tdtid 
   WHERE tasks_done.tdtid is null 
   ORDER BY tasks.tamount DESC LIMIT 10
```

А ответ [@Rams666](/users/5002/rams666) помечаю как правильный, так как помог с направлением.

[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz), тебе тоже спасибо большое за помощь. Напиши что-то в виде ответа, я поставлю палец вверх, чтобы к тебе карма начислилась :)

Comment: Лениво разбираться с explain, но, насколько я понимаю, это хуже, чем вложенный запрос.